# MySQL Query - Create a Trigger that updates stock levels once a sale takes place

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I need to create a trigger to update my stock levels every time a product is purchased. I'm very new to MySQL so any help would be greatly appreciated and, please, if you can formulate an answer as if you're explaining it to a 5-year old child, that would be great :)

I have two tables which seem appropriate for this, with Product_ID common to both;

- **Products** (Product_ID, Category_ID, Supplier_ID, Product_Name, Description, Size,  Colour, Cost_Price_Eur, Selling_Price_Eur, Total_Stock)
- **Order_Details** (Order_Details_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, Quantity_Sold)

Any attempt to date has failed. In fact, I just get the following;

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'on order_details' at line 1

after the most basic of code below;

```
USE Shoes_By_Sean_Online

CREATE TRIGGER Stock_Update on order_details
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered looking at [the documentation for CREATE TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html), or any [examples of working syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)?

Comment: Hi Bill...I've viewed multiple explanations and examples relating to stock / inventory changes but have not come unstuck. I can't even explain why I'm getting the Error code!

Comment: Sorry for deleting there, I was hoping to present it in a more legible manner. Yes, I am trying to work on it as we speak, hence the change from earlier. The errors are different yes, but both remain Error Code: 1064.

Comment: USE Shoes_By_Sean_Online

CREATE TRIGGER Stock_Update
AFTER INSERT
   ON order_details FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE products
SET products.Total_Stock = products.Total_Stock - New.Quantity_Sold
WHERE products.Product_ID = New.Product_ID;

END;

Comment: I suggest you edit your original question above to add the current attempt, instead of squeezing it into a comment (speaking of making it more legible). Include the _complete_ error message. And tell us how you are using DELIMITER, if you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Delimiter
And you can add the schema to the table

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER Stock_Update 
 AFTER INSERT ON Shoes_By_Sean_Online.order_details 
 FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
    UPDATE products 
      SET products.Total_Stock = products.Total_Stock - New.Quantity_Sold 
    WHERE products.Product_ID = New.Product_ID;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: nbk, thanks very much. I have it now and have to thank you for that. Much appreciated!